# Get length of text in div generated with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having .php document with a lot of string in array. My page takes one of them and puts into empty div named **post**. When I want to get length of post its always :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

So I assume that my jQuery code reads `<div class="post"></div>` which is blank untill website loads and generates text into that. So how can i get lenght of generated string from my post.php document?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      function getPost()
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'posts.php',
          dataType: 'html',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            $('.post').html(result);
          },
        });
      }
      getPost();
    </script>
  </head>
  <script>
    var postPoints = $(".post").val().length;
  </script>
  <body>
    <div class="post"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**posts.php**

```
<?php
    $posts = array(
      "string1",
      "string2",
      "string3",
      "string4"
    );

    $maxPosts = sizeof($posts);
    $generatePost = rand(0,$maxPosts);
    if($lastPost != $generatePost)
    {
      echo $posts[$generatePost];
      $lastPost = $generatePost;
    }
    else
    {
      $generatePost = rand(0,$maxPosts);
      echo $posts[$generatePost];
      $lastPost = $generatePost;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Work with ID's like `$("#mypost")`. Because you will  get an array back if selector is an css-class! And better do   `var postPoints = $("mypost").val();`  and `alert(postPoints.length);`

Comment: And move you `postPoints = ...` into the success method after `$('.post').html(result);`. That will ensure that the divs are there, before you access it. And please add your `<script>` after the HTML-Node `<div>`. Currently you accessing a div that isnt rendered at this point.

Comment: Final note: `</head><script></script><body>` is wrong HTML syntax. `<script>` must be within `<head>` or `<body>`.

Answer (score 3):

First the script `var postPoints = $(".post").val().length;` can't find the post div at all that why you're getting `undefined` error message :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

And that because you're trying to get the div before the page is fully loaded (That could be fixed using ready function) :

```
$(function(){
    var postPoints = $(".post").val().length;
})
```

This way the script will find your div **but it will always return '0'**.

So you should get the `length` after getting the response of the ajax request, you've to put your line inside the success callback :

```
success: function(result) {
    $('.post').html(result);
    alert( $(".post").val().length );
},
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPost()
{
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'posts.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('.post').html(result);
            var length = result.length; //for further uses, you may also assign this value with global variable.
        },
    });
}
```